# column structure in <select> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve column structure in `<select>` through CSS, I tried a lot but didn't succeed.

[image]

The HTML I tried,

```
<select id="select-bill-period">
    <option>Select a bill period</option>
    <option><span>Current bill</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&pound;21.99</span></option>
    <option><span>20 Oct 2015</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&pound;45.99</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Archived</span></option>
    <option><span>20 Oct 2015</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&pound;45.99</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Archived</span></option>
    <option><span>20 Oct 2015</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&pound;45.99</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Archived</span></option>
</select>
```

Doing `&nbsp;` is not the feasible solution for me, I know we can't use `<span>` tag or any other tag inside `<option>`  tag. Is ther any solution to acheive the column section in `<select>` box.

Comment: If you need that level of control you'd normally build a pseudo-select control using a `<ul>` or whatever, so that you can style each item however you like.

Comment: The person who voted -ve can you please give the solution for this ?

Comment: @nnnnnn, thanks for the solution, but i need the select box. Not just a drop down button or `Ul` `LI` structure. The user select the one and according to that i have to show them which one user has selected and according to that i have to show the results. Hence that is not a solution for me.

Comment: I meant that you would also attach appropriate event handlers and so forth so that from the user's point of view it behaves much like a standard select element, but you'd have full control over its appearance - you don't have to code this all from scratch, because there are jQuery plugins that do it automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var spacesToAdd = 2;
var biggestLength = 0;
$("#timezones option").each(function(){
var len = $(this).text().length;
    if(len > biggestLength){
        biggestLength = len;
    }
});
var padLength = biggestLength + spacesToAdd;
$("#timezones option").each(function(){
    var parts = $(this).text().split('+');
    var strLength = parts[0].length;
    for(var x=0; x<(padLength-strLength); x++){
        parts[0] = parts[0]+' '; 
    }
    $(this).text(parts[0].replace(/ /g, '\u00a0')+''+parts[1]).text;
});
```

```css
select{
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="timezones" id="timezones">
    <option value="1">Current bill +21.99</option>
    <option value="2">20Jan 2016 +20.54</option>
     <option value="3">20Dec 2018 +102.65</option>
    <option value="3">20Nov 2016 +502.62</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think this solution works only with monospace fonts like "Courier'.

Comment: Hi @Roma, thanks for your suggestion. I just modified your logic just a bit. And it is working fine for me. Thanks again. I have posted my solution below, If you want to look.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jQuery, I have found a jQuery plugin that will help you create something as per your requirement, find the link below:

**[multiple column select box](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Forms-and-Controls-C-C/Jquery-Multi-Column-Selectbox-54203.html)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper answer according to my structure... Thanks to @Roma. i have taken the same logic, but modified a bit. And this solution is working fine with my defined font. No require of `font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace`.

```
$("#select-bill-period option").each(function(){
    var optionObj = $(this).text();

    if(optionObj.indexOf('+') > -1){ 
        optionObj = optionObj.split('+'); //if the string has + sign, split the string with + sign;

        //If the option has 2 column
        if(optionObj.length == 2){
            var strLength = optionObj[0].length - 1;

            for(var x=0; x< strLength; x++){
                optionObj[0] = optionObj[0]+' '; 
            }

            //Merge the text for the option
            $(this).text(optionObj[0].replace(/ /g, '\u00a0')+''+optionObj[1]);

        }else{
            var strLength = optionObj[0].length - 4;

            for(var x=0; x < strLength; x++){
                optionObj[0] = optionObj[0]+' '; //Add space after the 1st column
                optionObj[1] = optionObj[1]+' '; //Add space after the 2nd column                   
            }

            //Merge the text for the option
            $(this).text(optionObj[0].replace(/ /g, '\u00a0')+''+optionObj[1].replace(/ /g, '\u00a0')+optionObj[2]);
        }

    }else{ 
        $(this).text(optionObj); //else the text will be as it is, no need to append any space;
    }
});
```